# Is there any better way to do the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

Here is my sql,but I think it's too complex,and maybe it's not very quick and efficient ? am i right? or is there a better way?

```
SELECT  TEventInfoid ,A.TTNum,
    CASE WHEN TModelid = 3822 THEN ( SELECT title
                                     FROM   dbo.sns_event WHERE id=TEventInfoid
                                   )
         ELSE ( SELECT  name
                FROM    dbo.sns_exhibition WHERE id=TEventInfoid
              )
    END,
    CASE WHEN TModelid = 3822 THEN ( SELECT start_time
                                     FROM   dbo.sns_event WHERE id=TEventInfoid
                                   )
         ELSE ( SELECT  start_Time
                FROM    dbo.sns_exhibition WHERE id=TEventInfoid
              )
    END,
    CASE WHEN TModelid = 3822 THEN ( SELECT [address]
                                     FROM   dbo.sns_event WHERE id=TEventInfoid
                                   )
         ELSE ( SELECT  [address]
                FROM    dbo.sns_exhibition WHERE id=TEventInfoid
              )
    END
   FROM    
       T_Ticktets A
   WHERE A.TTNum='100229143644'
```

Comment: OK, I use MSSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.TEventInfoid, t.TTNum,
       (CASE WHEN t.TModelid = 3822 THEN e.title ELSE ex.name END),
       (CASE WHEN t.TModelid = 3822 THEN e.start_time ELSE ex.start_time END),
       (CASE WHEN t.TModelid = 3822 THEN e.address ELSE ex.address END)
FROM T_Ticktets t LEFT JOIN
     dbo.sns_event e
     ON e.id = t.TEventInfoid LEFT JOIN  -- unclear which table which is in
     dbo.sns_exhibition ex
     ON ex.id = t.TEventInfoid AND
        e.id IS NULL                     -- unclear which table which is in
WHERE t.TTNum = '100229143644';
```

Note:  The `join` conditions may have the wrong tables.  It is unclear which column which is in which table.

Also, if `TTNum` is declared as a big integer or numeric, you can drop the single quotes around the value being compared to.

This version *does* make an assumption.  It assumes that there are not multiple rows in the *other* table for a given `id`.  If that is the case, it would not be too hard to adjust the query.

EDIT:

The way to fix that last problem is simply:

```
SELECT t.TEventInfoid, t.TTNum,
        COALESCE(e.title, ex.name),
        COALESCE(e.start_time, ex.start_time),
        COALESCE(e.address, ex.address)
FROM T_Ticktets t LEFT JOIN
     dbo.sns_event e
     ON e.id = t.TEventInfoid AND t.TModelid = 3822 LEFT JOIN  -- unclear which table which is in
     dbo.sns_exhibition ex
     ON ex.id = t.TEventInfoid AND t.TModelid <> 3822          -- unclear which table which is in
WHERE t.TTNum = '100229143644';
```

This is probably the best form for the query.  Note:  if `TModelid` could be `NULL`, you would have to take that into account in the second `ON` condition.

Comment: the TModelid won't be NULL forever.

Comment: @jasonLam . . . I'm not sure what your comment refers to.  I'm just saying the second condition in the last query would be `ex.id = t.TEventInfoid AND (t.TModelid <> 3822  or t.TModelId IS NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
   SELECT 
        TEventInfoid ,A.TTNum,
        CASE WHEN TModelid = 3822 THEN e.title ELSE x.name END,
        CASE WHEN TModelid = 3822 THEN e.start_time ELSE x.start_Time END,
        CASE WHEN TModelid = 3822 THEN e.[address] ELSE x.[address] END
    FROM    
       T_Ticktets A
       LEFT JOIN dbo.sns_event e ON e.id=A.TEventInfoid
       LEFT JOIN dbo.sns_exhibition x  WHERE x.id=A.TEventInfoid
     WHERE A.TTNum='100229143644'
```

Comment: 3Q, I think it's more comfortable

Answer (score 1):

How would you say this to yourself?  I want all of the events where the ticket model id is 3822 and all of the exhibits where it is not 3822.

```
SELECT A.TEventInfoid,
A.TTNum,
e.Title,
e.start_time,
e.[address],
A.TModelid
FROM T_Ticktets A 
JOIN dbo.sns_event e
ON A.id = e.TEventInfoid
WHERE A.TTNum='100229143644'
AND A.TModelid = 3822

UNION ALL

SELECT A.TEventInfoid,
A.TTNum,
e.Name   
e.start_time,
e.[address],
A.TModelid
FROM T_Ticktets A 
JOIN dbo.sns_exhibition e
ON e.id = A.TEventInfoid
WHERE A.TTNum='100229143644'
AND A.TModelid <> 3822
```